# Animation artifacts with jQuery in Google chrome (red/blue shift)

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, animation

I am attempting to animate a DIV with  transparent background. JS is here -->  http://pastebin.com/fvK2FV5W

The animation works fine, but there are artifacts on-screen when animating left and right (up and down are not affected).

SYMPTOMS:

- When animating to the left, I get RED lines streaking off of the rightmost white pixels.
- When animating to the right, I get BLUE lines streaking off the leftmost white pixels. (see https://i.stack.imgur.com/2UQg6.png)
- Only happens when animating right/left, not up/down
- Chrome (17.0.9), jQuery (1.7.1), Windows 7

I've never seen this before, and it is only occurring in Chrome (v 17.0.9).

Any thoughts as to what might be causeing this?

---

EDIT // TESTS:

- When changing the color of the text from white to blue, and white to red - the streaks reflect the color of the text. Make text red...blue lines are black.  Make text blue...red lines are black.
- Disabled webGL - didn't change anything.
- The streaks only appear when the animation is moving slower than a certain speed.  When easing the animation out to the right, i get lines that look like https://i.stack.imgur.com/2UQg6.png
- Thanks to Beetroot-Beetroot for saying it might be a result of undue complexity in my code. looks like that might be the problem, still testing.

Comment: oh yes, this is the magic blue and red lines that you can see only when you animate a div left or right... but not top or down... seriously, give us some sample code man!

Comment: JS is not straight-forward, but animation section is: http://pastebin.com/fvK2FV5W

Comment: Does this only happen in Chrome? Try disabling Chrome's GPU acceleration, believe it or not I've seen rendering problems caused by it. Check chrome://flags/ for advanced options.

Comment: Disabled GPU vsync, and webGL independently -- but no dice :/

Answer (score 1):

Circusdei, your current code is way more complicated than it needs to be. Pleeeeease before you do anything else, get your mind round jQuery completion callbacks and animation chains - see [animate() in the jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/animate/).

To make something happen when a jQuery animation is complete, there's no need to anticipate completion with a separate `setTimeout`; instead, specify a "complete" callback function. For example the first case can be rewritten as follows ...

javascript:

```
case "top":
    slide.animate({top: verticalGutter+'px'}, slideTimeIn, 'easeInOutQuad', function(){
        slide.animate({top: (verticalGutter+extraSlide)+'px'}, slideTimeFloat, 'easeOutQuint', function(){
            slide.animate({
                top: (viewportHeight-slideHeight)+'px',
                opacity: 0
            }, slideTimeOut);
        });
    });
break;
```

Note how "what to do when it's finished" callback functions are given as the last argument of the outer two animations. The innermost animation doesn't have a callback.

This (several times over), together with the elimination of unnecessary line feeds, will shorten your code significantly. It will become more readable and may even get rid of the nasty red/blue lines artifact in Chrome.

EDIT: In fact it can be even simpler. As the subject of the sequential animations is the same in all three cases, jQuery allows you to establish an animation chain as follows:

javascript:

```
case "top":
    slide.animate({
        top: verticalGutter+'px'
    }, slideTimeIn, 'easeInOutQuad').animate({
        top: (verticalGutter+extraSlide)+'px'
    }, slideTimeFloat, 'easeOutQuint').animate({
        top: (viewportHeight-slideHeight)+'px',
        opacity: 0
    }, slideTimeOut);
break;
```

EDIT 2: See http://pastebin.com/aHxUsL78 to see just how much the code might simplify.

Comment: i was in the middle of playing with animations and noticed the lines. thank you for the critique, but it's not really an answer to my question.

Comment: currently reworking/consolidating the code...will see if that helps.

Comment: hrm -- seems as though the consolidation might have fixed the lines. still testing.

Comment: @circusdei Keep me up to date. Intrigued to know what you end up with.

Comment: went with hybrid css3 and jquery animations -- seemed to take care of it.  still not sure what was causing it.

Comment: OK, it's like that sometimes.

Answer (score 1):

See the [accepted stackoverflow answer here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9674267/fix-blue-line-on-google-chrome?rq=1)

In short: adding 1px of left or right padding to the affected element sorted out the problem for me! Something to do with a font redraw / rendering glitch in webkit.