# Fix blue line on Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, animation

I have the following HTML:

```
<div id="a"><div id="b">aga ad gdas ga gs ds da dgs sd ds dg gdgsdgwa</div></div>
```

And CSS:

```
#a, #b {
    position: absolute; 
    height: 10px;
    font-size: 10px;   
    white-space:nowrap;
    display: block;
}
#a {
    width: 200px;   
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

And Javascript:

```
var x = 0;

setInterval(function() {
    if ($('#b').position().left < (-$('#b').width())) {
        x = 305;
    }
    $('#b').css('left', (x--) + 'px')
}, 50);
```

Which runs fine in Firefox and Internet Explorer, however on Google Chrome 17 it shows a blue line at the end of the sentence. [See live jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ujr8V/1/).

[image: Blue line on Google Chrome]

How can I fix it?

Comment: @Blindy Some texts work fine, but this one ending with the `a` or `w` will make the line to appear. It may be some rendering issue of Google Chrome...

Comment: Not seeing any line on Chrome 17.0.963.79 m.

Comment: @j08691 FWIW, I see it on 17.0.963.79 on mac

Comment: in the future please do not use jsfiddle to show us very small amounts of CSS and HTML. If jsfiddle is down this post would be useless; please include the relevant code in the question so it is searchable and standalone.

Comment: @JeffAtwood I took the Javascript from there and added to the question, so all the code that is there is also in the post.

Comment: @RedDragon thank you, this is a helpful q and it is even better with the code inline, so it can help more people in the future. Also note I get similar artifacts in ie10 metro as well so it is not just chrome...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that it's a font redraw/rendering glitch. I've seen it in Java. It probably has little to do with your JS and CSS (fortunately and unfortunately).

The trick is to force it to redraw where the streak is being made. Fortunately, that's easily fixed in this scenario: just add `padding-right:1px;` to the `#b` element.

---

Edit: You may want to consider submitting this bug to Google/Apple (as the problem occurs in both Chrome and Safari).

Comment: This works. Please fix the padding:right to padding-right as it won't let me submit a change request by changing only one char at the answer.

Comment: wouldn't the common denominator be WebKit?

Comment: @antony.trupe I suppose. In any case, it seems to be fixed in both Chrome and Safari now.

Answer (score 6):

Interestingly, the lighter the BG color, the lighter the erroneous blue line. [Font-smoothing](http://www.usabilitypost.com/2010/08/26/font-smoothing/) did not fix it.

1px `padding-right` fixes it (I added -1px `margin-right` to compensate).

http://jsfiddle.net/MqQG3/1/

Comment: Would font-smoothing usually fix a problem like this?

Comment: @JeffreySweeney - it could. It looks like the problem is related to a trailing anti-aliased edge pixel on a character; in theory changing the smoothing type could modify that.

Comment: Also, if you zoom in, it actually looks like a single dot from the edge of a serif at the baseline of the font.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem and solved it using Math.floor() to integerise my width, height and background-size properties...