# jQuery slider render bug

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, google-chrome, jquery-ui-slider

I'm getting a strange redraw bug in chrome with jQuery slider (image below) after sliding. Anyone else get this issue and is there a fix?

[image: jQuery slider redraw bug]

Comment: are you getting this on your webpage, or just in a fiddle?

Comment: I'm getting it in the web page.

Comment: Just making sure - this issue sometimes occurs in fiddles but not on the actual web page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually a well-known issue with Chrome. Check out the following posts:

[Animating a DIV with JavaScript renders artifacts on Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11924986/animating-a-div-with-javascript-renders-artifacts-on-chrome)

[Fix blue line on Google Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9674267/fix-blue-line-on-google-chrome?rq=1)

Comment: I added -webkit-perspective: 1000; -webkit-backface-visibility:hidden; and that seems to fix the problem.